# Why isn't the first input for a string not being assigned to an std::string object?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, input

I wrote a program in which there is a class. In this class there is an overloaded function call operator which takes an `std::istream` object and `std::string` object and has a `while` loop in which we indefinitely take input and concatenate to the `std::string` parameter.

The problem is that the first input is not being used to be concatenated into the `std::string` parameter. Although I fixed the problem, I'm unable to understand why is this happening.

This is the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class PrintString {
public:
 void operator() (istream& is, string &ss) {

   // string s; (1)
    while (is >> ss) {
        ss += ss;
    }

    if (is)
        ss = "";

}
/* 
 * (1): I fixed this by defining another std::string object 
 * and using that to assign to ss. After I did this everything 
 * is working as I wanted it to be.
 */
 };

int main() {

   cout << "enter some words, press ctrl+d to quit\n";
   vector<string> vec;
   PrintString obj;

   string s1;
   s1.clear();
   obj(cin,s1);
   vec.push_back(s1);

   for (const auto &elem: vec)
        cout << elem;

   return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
enter some words, press ctrl+d to quit
amsndjanjskndna. <- This is the first input
mnmn, <- This is the second input
mnmn,mnmn, <- But in the output the first input is not seen
```

On my system I'm using Xcode version 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it failed was that your

```
is >> ss
```

overwrited everything that has been stored in `ss` from previous reads. So if you had something in `ss` already, it will be replaced by the newly-read string.

As you write, you can fix this by reading into an additional variable:

```
string s_read;
while (is >> s_read) {
    ss += s_read;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting content of your string by passing input directly to it:

```
while (is >> ss) // '>>' overwrites current content of 'ss'
{
    ss += ss; //then appends it to itself (now 'ss' holds doubled content)
}
```

Use temporary `std::string` to hold input from `stdin` just as you did:

```
string input;
while (is >> input)
{
    ss += input;
}
```

Also, if you want to know more about

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str)
```

read [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/).